# Fontawsome Icon are not loading in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I added a couple of circles on my app it worked for a couple of days but today it's not working [out put image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZS32.png)

```
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';

<FontAwesome name="circle" size={20} color="#25D366" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note: Expo has had issue with vector-icons

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5100#issuecomment-516725371

you can try updating expo version and deleting node_modules and npm install

If issue still persists , you might need to look for different plugin expo.

If you are willing replace Expo with react-native-cli, then there is a very good plugin availible , you can install

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Add the following line at the end of the

```
android/app/build.gradle
```

file

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

and then build again.

Comment: do u mean in the fonts.gradle file

Comment: it is for android , if you are building it in android, you would have android folder

Comment: im not building it in android studio if thats what u mean im using vs code

Comment: expo/vector-icons is build over react-native vector-icons, for which need to add the following in android folder, expo doesn't have an android folder because it itself take care of android and ios folder, but if you need to add the directory you can check expo detach

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if it helps

Comment: now im getting this error  `No inputs were found in config file '/Users/suhailmisbah/Documents/Projects/myposturelife/node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/tsconfig.json'. Specified 'include' paths were '["./src"]' and 'exclude' paths were '["**/__mocks__/*","**/__tests__/*"]'.`

Comment: seems a typescript Issue, check following link ,https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17155

Comment: thanks for help i ran this commend `TypeScript: Restart TS server` then it worked